# Can I change screenshots of the app after published?

Tags: android, google-maps, publish

I made an app  and put that on Playstore. Is there a way I can change the screenshots of the app? Or if it is not possible will the update version remove the previous version and screenshots?

Comment: yes, you can change the screenshots from the same place where you upload it first time, from your developer console account/publish page

Comment: You can update all the facts about you app (description text, images etc) as many times as you like and whenever you like, it won't remove the previous version.

Comment: Starting from November 2, 2020 you will need to do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062829/1151916

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can change the screenshots if you go to the [Google Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).

You select your app from the list, then go to store presence and select store listing from the menu on the left and there will be a graphic assets section on the page. You can add them there.

Comment: will the update version remove the previous version of the app?

Comment: It won't ask you to submit a new .apk file. It will just update the images.

Comment: now that i'm here on dev console what do i do next?

Comment: You select your app from the list, then go to store listing from the menu on the left and there will be a graphic assets section on the page. You can add them there

Comment: Your last comment should be added to the answer to make it more precise. Just saying to go to the google dev console is not a sufficient answer, and am tempted to downvote.

Comment: @Catalina What's time should I wait before updates released on google play?

Answer (score 30):

**Steps to update Screenshots on Android Developer Console**

1. Select the App to which the screenshot to be added from the list of App

[image]

2. From the Left click on **Store preference**, and inside that select **Store listing**.
   [image]
3. Scroll down on that page and you can see **Graphic Assets**, from there you can add

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Perfect, Now it will be in "Shop Display->shop information".

Answer (score 24):

In the new Google Play Console screenshots can be added like this:

1. List item
2. Tap on "**All apps**"
3. Pick one of your apps
4. Store presence
5. Main store listing
6. Scroll to Phone screenshots
7. Add screenshots.

[image]

Old Google Play Console will be discontinued from November 2, 2020.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Login and then go to All applications( from side menu)
3. Select your uploaded application
4. Then Store presence -> Store listing (form side menu)
5. On that page you'll find Graphic Assets section where you'll get different tabs for different devices(eg. PHONE, TABLET, ANDROID TV, WEAR OS) , there you can upload your application screenshots using the BROWSE FILES button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where you can manage your app’s graphic assets on the Play Console:

Sign in to your Play Console.
       Click All Applications All applications.

```
   Select an app.

   On the left menu, click Store Presence > Store listing.

   Under "Graphic assets", you can upload your images and add a YouTube video.
```